# Check a database for duplicate ID value then insert if or do nothing based on another value in the row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database structure as follows:

```
id       group     stat

123      abc       1
345      fdg       0
```

I need to check first if a duplicate "id" exists in the database. If there is no duplicate a new row can be inserted. If a duplicate "id" exists I need to check if "stat" is a 1 or a 0. If "stat" is set to 0 I want to do nothing. If "stat" is set to 1 I would like to INSERT a new row, duplicate "id"s are ok as users can be in more than one group.

I am a complete noob so any help is appreciated.

Comment: which database are you using ? is it mysql ?

Comment: The database is in MySQL 5.0.96

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT 123, 'def', 1
  FROM Table1
 WHERE 
( 
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table1
 WHERE id = 123 AND stat = 1
) > 0
LIMIT 1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ba5b/1)** demo. *Note that a second `INSERT` won't happen.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to check against duplicates (replace ? for the id you are checking for) and then query the count variable to continue your logic.

```
select id, count(*) as count
from table
where id = ?
group by id
having count > 1
```

Adding in pseudo-php code for completion:

```
<?php
$specifiedId = '123'
$query = "select id, count(*) from table where id =".$specifiedId."group by id having count(*) > 1"
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($result->num_rows == 0){
    //insert new record 
}else{
    $query2 = "select * from table where stat = 1 and id = ".$specifiedId;
    $result = $mysqli->query($query2);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        //insert new record 
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is only for checking duplicate where is the insert/update in your sql?

Comment: With separate statements to do the check, and then do the insert, there's a potential for a race condition. Consider two simultaneous processes that attempt to insert the same row. It's possible that both processes detect that the row does not exist, and then both processes will attempt to insert the row.

Comment: That is true.  However if you use transactions you can mitigate this.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO  (id,group,stat) VALUES (,,) ON DUPLICATE KEY ;

you can also use the case statement with the above

SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
    ->     WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
        -> 'one'
mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN 1>0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END;
        -> 'true'
mysql> SELECT CASE BINARY 'B'
    ->     WHEN 'a' THEN 1 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 END;
        -> NULL

I don't have mysql installed so please try this and post if it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A statement like this will meet your specification:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `group`, `stat`)
SELECT 345     AS `id`
     , 'foo'   AS `group`
     , 1       AS `stat`
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM `mytable` d
          WHERE ( d.id = 345 AND d.stat = 1 AND d.group = 'foo' )
             OR ( d.id = 345 AND d.stat = /*constant*/ 0 )
       )
```

Note that in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery, the all of the values specified on the right side of the equality predicates are the same values being inserted  ('345','foo','1'), with the exception of the constant `0` (in the check of d.stat in the OR portion.)

(Note that this does allow a `stat=0` row to be inserted if there are `stat=1` rows for the same `id`. I believe this behavior meets the specification, but I see room for some interpretation there.  I've made an assumption that the combination of (id,group,stat) should be UNIQUE (there should be no duplicates), and that the combination if (id,stat=0) should also be unique.

You can determine if a row was inserted or not by examining the affected rows count returned.

There are some benefits to performing the check for a duplicate within the insert:

- (usually) better performance (due to fewer round trips to the database)
- avoids race condition of two (or more) processes simultaneously checking/inserting same values
- simpler application code (fewer lines)

Including a comment about what the SQL statement is supposed to be doing will be very beneficial for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this

```
select * from taske3 where emp_id=$employee_id AND taskdate=$date ;
$num_of_rows = query_rows ;

      if(num_of_rows == 1){
echo "time for the particular project at the given date is already inserted";
          }
    else {
insert into task3 ('e_id','project','task','time','taskdate') VALUES     
     ('$employee_id','$projectassignedto','2','$date');
  }
```

check to see where an entry exists , by running select query . Count the rows , if entry exits count will be 1 else 0 and then accordingly u can enter the data into database